# Sharing uploadArchives task across modules

Tags: android, maven, gradle, maven-publish

I'm working on a repo with a set of releasable libraries each in a module. The idea is each library should be able to be released individually with i.e., `./gradlew upload`.

Currently in each module I have the following code to publish it:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "<url>") {
                authentication(userName: System.getenv('USER_NAME'), password: System.getenv('PASSWORD'))
                pom.groupId = "$groupId"
                pom.artifactId = "$artifactId"
                pom.version = android.defaultConfig.versionName
            }
        }
    }
}

afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            library(MavenPublication) {
                setGroupId "$groupId"
                setArtifactId "$artifactId"
                version android.defaultConfig.versionName

                artifact bundleReleaseAar
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd love to have a way to share those gradle tasks and to avoid repeating them in each module but haven't found a way to do that. One tricky thing probably is that `artifactId` would be different in each module so assuming I could extract those gradle tasks there should be a way to set `artifactId` individually.

Can someone shed me some light? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can put all of your code into a simple `build.gradle` and use `apply from:` to apply to multiple `build.gradle` files.

For instance, I have this [compile.gradle](https://github.com/jaredsburrows/cs-interview-questions/blob/master/gradle/compile.gradle) script that I use in many places: [kotlin/build.gradle](https://github.com/jaredsburrows/cs-interview-questions/blob/master/kotlin/build.gradle) and [java/build.gradle](https://github.com/jaredsburrows/cs-interview-questions/blob/master/java/build.gradle).

Instead of writing your own "publishing" `build.gradle`, I would suggest you a popular script that is open source and readily available, [gradle-mvn-push.gradle](https://github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/blob/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle).

Here is an example setup for your project:

```
root
 |
 | gradle
 | --- gradle-mvn-mpp-push.gradle
 |
 | - module a
 | --- build.gradle - apply from: rootProject.file("gradle/gradle-mvn-mpp-push.gradle")
 |
 | - module b
 | --- build.gradle - apply from: rootProject.file("gradle/gradle-mvn-mpp-push.gradle")
 |
```

See the docs here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:script_plugins